# Warning: require_once(C:\laragon\www\hrm/public/index.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\laragon\www\hrm\server.php on line

Tags: laravel

Hey I am using laragon I have an old project where I have my index.php in
[Here image][1]

but it,s not running
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTM1q.png

Comment: You forgot to share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing forward and back slashes together in the path to the index, use only backslashes.

Otherwise, code examples are needed for context as the other commenter stated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).